# HAproxy freeze / crash / stops accepting cottections

Tags: haproxy

I've seen similar posts for my issue but none of them seem to be relevant for my case.
I've had my HAproxy configured for the past 3 months roughly the same and did not encounter any issues. The server was protected by 2 firewalls and was prevented access from the internet (FW configured to allow http/s access from my HQ IP).
Last week I've opened it to the world, performed a lot of stress tests and all seemed ok.
A couple of hours AFTER my tests were done my frontend server did not respond, not even the stats page could load.

Checking my monitoring system did not show any high CPU, RAM or Bandwidth.
Though the stats page did not load I monitor the stats page from an SNMP monitor system and could see that the max concurrent connections to the entire HAproxy server was ~700, not even close to the global maxconn 10000 (fullconn is 10000 as well).

Restarting the HAproxy service solved the issue temporarily as the issue resurfaced a couple of hours later.

I currenly have HAproxy 1.5.3 installed and though I've read the http://www.haproxy.org/download/1.5/src/CHANGELOG I'm not sure this issue was addressed in later releases.

Any assistance with this issue will be more then welcome.

Here is my config:

```
global
log             127.0.0.1       local0
   chroot      /var/lib/haproxy
    pidfile     /var/run/haproxy.pid
    maxconn     10000
    user        haproxy
    group       haproxy
    daemon
    tune.ssl.default-dh-param 2048

stats socket /etc/haproxy/haproxysock level admin
stats socket /var/run/haproxy.stat mode 666

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
Defaults
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
defaults
    mode                    http
    log                     global
    option                  httplog
    option                  dontlognull
    option http-server-close
    option forwardfor       except 127.0.0.0/8
    option                  redispatch
    retries                 3
    timeout http-request    10s
    timeout queue           1m
    timeout connect         5s
    timeout client          1m
    timeout server          1m
    timeout http-keep-alive 10s
    timeout check           10s
    maxconn                 10000

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# main frontend which proxys to the backends
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
frontend main
bind *:80
bind site1.app.company.com:443 ssl crt /etc/haproxy/ssl/app/apppublic.pem no-sslv3
bind site2.company.com:443 ssl crt /etc/haproxy/ssl/public.pem no-sslv3
bind site3.company.net:443 ssl crt /etc/haproxy/ssl/net.pem no-sslv3
redirect scheme https code 301 if !{ ssl_fc }

        acl rule1  hdr_dom(host) -i site1.app.company.com
        use_backend site1 if rule1
    acl rule2  hdr_dom(host) -i site2.company.com
    use_backend site2 if rule2
    acl rule3  hdr_dom(host) -i site3.company.net
    use_backend site3 if rule3

    default_backend             site1

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# round robin balancing between the various backends
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
backend site1
mode http
    fullconn                 10000
    balance     roundrobin
option httpclose
option forwardfor
cookie SERVERID insert indirect nocache
    server  Server1   1.1.1.1:443 cookie A check ssl verify none
    server  Server2   2.2.2.1:443 cookie B check ssl verify none

backend wwwsest
mode http
    fullconn                 10000
    balance     roundrobin
option httpclose
option forwardfor
cookie SERVERID insert indirect nocache
http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Proto https if { ssl_fc }
http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Port %[dst_port]
    server  Server1   1.1.1.2:443 cookie A check ssl verify none inter 3000 fall 2 rise 2
    server  Server2   2.2.2.2:443 cookie B check ssl verify none inter 3000 fall 2 rise 2

backend internalst
mode http
    fullconn                 10000
    balance     roundrobin
option httpclose
option forwardfor
cookie SERVERID insert indirect nocache
http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Proto https if { ssl_fc }
http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Port %[dst_port]
    server Server1   10.0.0.1:443 cookie A check ssl verify none inter 3000 fall 2 rise 2
    server Server2   10.0.0.2:443 cookie B check ssl verify none inter 3000 fall 2 rise 2

#Statistics server:
listen stats *:1936
bind *:1936 ssl crt /etc/haproxy/ssl/app/apppublic.pem
    stats enable
    stats uri /
    stats hide-version
    stats refresh 30s
    stats auth admin:********
```

Comment: Can you post your full configuration file?

Comment: @Yuval: Please fix the markup for your config. It's impossible to read like this!

Comment: oops... sorry :-) fixed it.

Comment: So can anyone assist?